# Cout prints incorrect values of Bidimensional int array, while code appears to be correct

Tags: arrays, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, warnings

Following code appears to be correct, yet it will print incorrect numbers, which are random each time! I literally copied it from C++ site and cross checked it to confirm the code is correct! And it still doesn't work!

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a[3][4] = {
       {0, 1, 2, 3} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 0 */
       {4, 5, 6, 7} ,   /*  initializers for row indexed by 1 */
       {8, 9, 10, 11}   /*  initializers for row indexed by 2 */
    };
    std::cout << a[3][4];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize arrays in c++, the number passed into each bracket is the size of the array, however this is the upper bound, which is not actually an index, its the limit. if your index starts at 0, and you have 3 items in the arrray, then your last row would be 2. This is why c++ loops over the array are always

```cpp
for(int i =0; i < array_size; i++)
```

With an emphisis on `<` and not `<=`.
In your code, your indexing an item out of bounds; since a[3][4] is technically the 4th col 5th row.
C++ will let you index out of bounds, and your actually just indexing random values out in memory, which isn't good.
Try printing `a[2][3]` and that should be what your expecting.

Comment: Thing is I already tried that and I get: C2078 too many initializers, 3x E0146 too many initializer values. I don't know what is going on!!! Strange! They have it the same way I have: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidimensional-arrays-c-cpp/

Comment: What exactly did you try? I just ran your code, exactly copy pasted as you posted it, with the exception of `std::cout << a[2][3];`, and it worked fine, printing `11`.

Comment: What you said: substituting a[3][4] for a[2][3].

Comment: if you put `std::cout << a[2][3];` then it should work... as i said i copy pasted your exact code and it worked fine when i replaced `a[3][4]` with `a[2][3]` on the last line. Your first line should still be `a[3][4]`, only the last line should be `a[2][3]`

Comment: Then I don't understand it, I created a new project just for this and copied code here from there and it still doesn't work... while code is correct! But if I create another project: it works now hmm...

Comment: Can you give a screenshot link of exactly what your running that is still giving you errors

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qVzDUnZ This was a new project, it doesn't work again strange. Also don't you have to print array using for loops? I already did that and it worked in different scenario! Not sure if cout works too, but even if I remove cout, I get still the same errors & warnings in this case!

Comment: it doesnt work because your initalizing with the wrong paramaters. When you declare an array, you declare how many items in each row / column. You have 3 rows and 4 columns, so you **initialize** it as `a[3][4] = ` bla bla. But when you index this array, you start at 0. you can NEVER index the bounds you used when initializing. if you initalize as `a[3][4]` then your indexes are `a[0-2][0-3]`, which is a total of 3x4 since we include 0.

Comment: The array you initialized in your screenshot is only 2x3, so youd only be able to index up to `a[0-1][0-2]`, but youll also get an error because the array you assigned it to is too big; its a 3x4 array. Read this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm

Comment: Yes ofc. right! I figured this yesterday, I just got confused to the point that I don't even, also there was one issue cooccuring. Thanks for explantion!